# How to get the parent folder name of Message with Exchangelib python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exchangelib

I have an Item object obtained by filtering on an account using exchangelib in python 3.7. It is an email object. I need to find the parent folder name of this item. I specifically need the **name** field of the folder(This is for tracking where specific emails are moved in a mailbox).

I can see a field parent_folder_id in the item object which returns what I think is a valid folder id. This is also for a production mailbox where `account.root.get_folder(folder_id=idObj)` times out due to Exchange settings which I cannot change. Pretty much any request which caches fails with a timeout.

```
account=Account(...)
mailItems=account.inbox.all().filter(subject="foo")
print([i.parent_folder_id.id for i in mailItems])
```

This prints a list of folder ids. I need the names of these folders. Unclear how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only searching `account.inbox` and not its subfolders, `parent_folder_id` will always point to `account.inbox`.

There's not a very good API yet for looking up folders by e.g. ID. The best solution currently is to use a folder QuerySet:

```py
from exchangelib.folders import SingleFolderQuerySet

f = SingleFolderQuerySet(
    account=account,
    folder=account.root
).get(id=i.parent_folder_id.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will try this and let you know