# Getting the name of a folder using Exchangelib

Tags: python, exchangelib

I have looked at:

[How to get the parent folder name of Message with Exchangelib python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66347574/how-to-get-the-parent-folder-name-of-message-with-exchangelib-python)

But have been unable to make this work using the following debugging code:

```
for item in docdead.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:3000]: #look into the inbox the first 3K emails order desc by date received
    if item.datetime_received < ews_bfr: #if the mail if older than the custom date in the EWS format then apply rule
        print (item.subject)
        print (item.datetime_received)
        print (item.sender.email_address)
        print (item.sender.name)
        print (item.body)
        print(SingleFolderQuerySet(
            account=account,
            folder=account.root
        ).get(id=item.parent_folder_id.id))
        for attachment in item.attachments:
            print (attachment.name)
```

I get:

`ValueError: EWS does not support filtering on field 'id'`

I am sure its a simple error, but I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just querying one folder, then `parent_folder_id` will always point to that folder.

If you're querying multiple folders at a time, here's the general way to look up a folder name by ID:

```py
from exchangelib.folders import FolderId, SingleFolderQuerySet

folder_name = SingleFolderQuerySet(
    account=account,
    folder=FolderId(id=item.parent_folder_id.id),
).resolve().name
```

Comment: Erik, thanks so much for providing this.  I am getting an error on FolderId - is this a variable I need to set (based on the current sub folder ID?) and I am also getting an error on self.account rather than account.  Apologies if I am asking naive question, what would code look like to get all messages and print the folder name of each? Thats my final goal, just trying to work it myself!

Comment: Sorry, fixed the example code now

Comment: Thanks Eric.  I have altered my code and still getting ''folder_name = SingleFolderQuerySet(
AttributeError: 'SingleFolderQuerySet' object has no attribute 'resolve''   I have imported: from exchangelib.folders import SingleFolderQuerySet, FolderId